# Set image as cursor in R Shiny

Tags: r, url, shiny, mouse-cursor

Is there a way to use a web image as cursor when hovering over a button?

I tried something like this:

```
tags$head(tags$style(HTML(" .custom {  cursor: url(https://c2.staticflickr.com/2/1907/31794847918_04f9e687e1_b.jpg), auto;
} ")))
```

which has no effect, and I can't find any other examples on the web how to manage this in R shiny.

```
library(shiny)

ui  <- fluidPage(    
  actionButton(inputId = 'messagebutton', label = 'click me')
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This example works for me. I think your image isnt working, but I'm not sure why exactly. It might be too big.

```
library(shiny)

csscode <- HTML("
#messagebutton {  
  cursor: url(http://www.javascriptkit.com/ajax.gif), auto;
}
")

ui  <- fluidPage(    
  tags$head(tags$style(csscode)),
  actionButton(inputId = 'messagebutton', label = 'click me')
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Comment: Ah yes I tried with some tiny images now too. Seems about 3kb limit